# Remove temporary files

Tags: auxiliary-files, build-system

I have just started working with LaTeX. I am using Sublime as my editor and have installed the Latextools package (https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools).

This works just fine although it is producing various files (.aux, .lof etc.). As I understand these files are required for different functionalities however as I see it these could be removed once the PDF file has been generated. If this is true I would appreciate if someone could give some advice on how to automatically accomplish this when building the PDF file.

Comment: As you have just started: Don't remove the files until you know what they are doing and when exactly they are no longer needed.

Comment: What are their purpose after the PDF have been build?

Comment: Once you are truly finished with the PDF then you can delete the aux files. Until then it is a waste of efforts. If you spot at typo and have to recompile, then you have to recompile several times in order to get the correct aux files.

Comment: Search for "auxiliary" on this site.

Comment: I have searched for a solution but I cannot find any answers that are targeted the sublime/Latextools build process. When people mention for instance: `pdflatex -output-directory=target <file>` I am not sure where to type this because i am just pressing Ctrl+b to build my PDF file.

Comment: Simply leave it. With your current knowledge you will probably remove the files at the wrong time and then wonder why your tableofcontents or the links or the references don't work or why the compilation takes so long. Go back to this question in one or two month.

Comment: The command you are asking about, `pdflatex -output-directory=target <file>`, is something you would run from the command line after navigating to the folder where your project is stored. Since you are using Sublime Text to 'compile' the document you will have to modify the command settings for Sublime Text (this is documented [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#compiling-latex-files)); I don't recommend that since you are pretty new to this. Alternately you could modify your sublime-project file to prevent the .aux files from appearing as part of the project.

Comment: You can remove some of the temporary files with `ctr+l backspace`. Doing it automatically requires some non-trivial changes (at least for the uninitiated) of the `builder_settings` in LaTeXTools.sublime-settings, and/or to set up a latexmkrc file in your project directory. LaTeXTools uses [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) as build engine. I guess this is not worth the effort in your situation.

Comment: I forgot to add that `latexmk` is used under TeXLive and MacTeX. In case of MikTeX, `texify` is responsible for handling the compilation process.

Comment: The Ctrl+l, Backspace command seems to work alright and if it as hard as you say, I guess it aint worth it, to implement that functionality into the build process. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: arara is also worth a look

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Sublime, but some LaTeX editors like TeXworks have the option of remove auxiliary files at any time. Others as TeXmaker have an option to use the `-output-directory=` option, others as LaTeXila optionally clean these files when the `.tex` file is closed, an others as  Gummi or Lyx use the temporal directory  (`/tmp` in Linux) instead of your working directory, so after a reboot your lost these files. At worse, you can make your own script to delete these files in the working directory.

So yes, you can safely remove auxiliary files once the PDF was fully generated. Sometimes you must do so when there are compilation problems. As long as you maintain all the source code (`.tex`, `. bib`, any local `.cls` and `.sty` file, images, etc.) all is fine, excepting that you could need again these files in the future, so premature cleaning  have the risk enlarge the build process (may be a lot of time for complex documents).